# reset index for a grouped dataframe

Tags: pandas

I groupby a dataframe and I'd like to reset the index with `reset_index()`. However, received an error indicates that it cannot insert a column because it already exists.
I understand how the error happened but don't know how to fix it.

```
d = {'c1':['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'], 'c2':['Low', 'High', 'Low', 'High', 'High', 'High']}
dd = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
dd.groupby('c1')['c2'].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100).reset_index()
```

it returns

```
c1  c2  
a   High     50.0
    Low      50.0
b   High     50.0
    Low      50.0
c   High    100.0
```

I'd like to make the dataframe look like this

```
c1  c2       percent
a   High     50.0
a   Low      50.0
b   High     50.0
b   Low      50.0
c   High    100.0
```

How to achive this ?

Answer (score 3):

Your code (with `reindex`) actually fails on my system since one of the levels has the same name with the `value_counts` series.

Try `reset_index` with `name`:

```
(dd.groupby('c1')['c2']
   .value_counts(normalize=True)
   .mul(100)
   .reset_index(name='percent')
)
```

Output:

```
  c1    c2  percent
0  a  High     50.0
1  a   Low     50.0
2  b  High     50.0
3  b   Low     50.0
4  c  High    100.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `c2` column already exists.
Instead you can try this to get your desire output:

```
df = dd.groupby('c1')['c2'].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100)\
                .to_frame().rename(columns={'c2': 'percent'}).reset_index()

print(df)

 c1    c2  percent
0  a  High     50.0
1  a   Low     50.0
2  b  High     50.0
3  b   Low     50.0
4  c  High    100.0
```